# Capybara Rspec routing incorrectly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm working on feature tests for my rails app and completely confused.  I've created a test to log in which is routing me back to my root path of `/`.

```
1) Sign in user can sign in with valid credentials
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content I18n.t 'devise.sessions.signed_in'
       expected to find text "Signed in successfully." in "Home Login This is where the fun is."
     # ./spec/features/users/sign_in_spec.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

In my spec file I have:

```
feature 'Sign in', :devise do
  scenario 'user can sign in with valid credentials' do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    signin(user.email, user.password)
    expect(page).to have_content I18n.t 'devise.sessions.signed_in'
  end
end
```

I created a `signin` method in a helper file that has:

```
module Features
  module SessionHelpers
  def signin(email, password)
      visit new_user_session_path
      fill_in 'Email', with: email
      fill_in 'Password', with: password
      click_button 'Log in'
    end
  end
end
```

For some reason this is routing me back to my root path, even though I should be in `/admin` at this point:

```
$rescue rspec

From: /Users/mine/Coding/project/spec/features/users/sign_in_spec.rb @ line 24 :

    19:   #   When I sign in with valid credentials
    20:   #   Then I see a success message
    21:   scenario 'user can sign in with valid credentials' do
    22:     user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    23:     signin(user.email, user.password)
 => 24:     expect(page).to have_content I18n.t 'devise.sessions.signed_in'
    25:   end
    26: 

RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: expected to find text "Signed in successfully." in "Home Login This is where the fun is."
from /Users/mine/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-support-3.6.0/lib/rspec/support.rb:87:in `block in <module:Support>'
[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::SignIn>)> current_path
=> "/"
```

When I do this all by hand through my own browser I'm able to log in without an issue and being redirected to the correct path `/admin`.  What am I missing?

Comment: What driver are you using with Capybara? and what Capybara settings are you using (`Capybara.server`, etc)?

Comment: you can use `gem "chromedriver-helper"` to figure out what exactly is working

Comment: So the signin should happen in some controller action where it checks the password. Does that succeed?

Comment: @Sunny The `chromedriver-helper` gem works by installing a shim into your ruby bins which can result in hard to debug issues where it's not running the version you think it is.  A better solution is the `webdrivers` gem which provides the same service but through a different method.